# What is the difference between from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split and from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Can anyone help me?
I am having hard time to know the difference between these

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

In the documentation I saw it is written

> "Split arrays or matrices into random train and test subsets"

for both of them.

Which should be used when??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split` is [deprecated](https://github.com/amueller/scipy_2015_sklearn_tutorial/issues/60), you should use

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`